# numpy apply "where" on one column?

Tags: python, numpy

```
[[11.  5.]
 [24.  6.]
 [39. 12.]
 [14.  1.]
 [25. 12.]]
```

That's my matrix, now I want to apply the following condition to it: 10 < a < 15 **but only to the first column**

As result I want an array with the indices
[0. 3.]

My attempts with "where" failed, numpy applied it to both columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first column is `a[:, 0]`. `np.flatnonzero` is a version of `np.nonzero` (which is `where` with only one argument) that returns a flat array instead of a tuple of indices.

You can do something like

```
mask = (10 < a[:, 0]) & (a[:, 0] < 15)
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
```

Another way is

```
idx, = np.nonzero(mask)
```

Or even

```
idx, = np.where(mask)
```

Notice the comma after `idx` in the last two examples, which triggers argument unpacking.

Comment: nice trick, ``10 >`` should read as ``10 <`` though